# Trouble extending scipy.stats.multivariate_normal [__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments]

Tags: python, inheritance, scipy, arguments, super

I'm trying to extend a base class ([scipy.stats.multivariate_normal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html)) but I'm having some difficulty with calling `super`'s `__init__`:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
class MVGaussian(multivariate_normal):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    # I want base class to handle all the arguments
        super(MVGaussian, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    # def myMethod ...
```

I always get `TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given`

I've also tried `super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)`, or just `multivariate_normal.__init__(*args, **kwargs)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to subclass `multivariate_normal`, but it isn't a class, it's an instance of a class that has defined a `__call__` method:

```
In [24]: isinstance(multivariate_normal, scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_gen)
Out[24]: True
```

You'll have to subclass `scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_gen` and make an instance of your class for it to behave like `multivariate_normal`:

```
from scipy.stats._multivariate import multivariate_normal_gen

class MVGaussian(multivariate_normal_gen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MVGaussian, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

mv_gaussian = MVGaussian()
```

Look at the source code for more info: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/8a6cf90358c40ab525dc4de5ffa74e4eed163eed/scipy/stats/_multivariate.py#L220-L430

Comment: Thanks! Turns out what I really want to extend is `multivariate_normal_frozen`